# Update a named range in excel (and all references to it)?

Tags: excel, excel-2007, vba

I used a period (.) in all my range names, which is fine for excel but not fine when I try to export to a google spreadsheet.

Is there an easy way to update all my range names (replace . with _ )? Copy&replace only handles the references and not the names themselves.

Or, in this case, another solution would be to replace name references with their normal table location (C5 etc..), the reverse of apply names. Is there a quick way to do that?

Comment: what do you thing of simple vba code? this shouldn't be difficult...

Answer (score 2):

VBA will be helpful in this situation. Please do the following:

1. open the workbook you have problem with
2. go to VBA Editor/IDE by pressing Alt+F11 in Excel app
3. in IDE >> Menu >> Insert >> Module
4. in code window (the biggest one) add the following code:

   ```
   Sub qReplace()

   Dim myName As Name
   For Each myName In ActiveWorkbook.Names

       myName.Name = Replace(myName.Name, ".", "_")

   Next
   End Sub
   ```
5. click inside it and press F5

Should work which I **tried and tested.**

Comment: Thank you; I'll have to bring this over to my netbook, because I'm on Excel 2008 for Mac which doesn't have VBA (frustrating!)

Answer (score 1):

I recommend Jan Karel Pieterse's [Name Manager](http://www.jkp-ads.com/officemarketplacenm-en.asp) addin. It's one of the great Excel development tools and, more specific to your needs, has a rename function that offers to update references throughout the workbook and code.

Of course, be sure to back up your work before doing something like this.